# Check whether selected option has no value, across multiple select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I try the below jQuery, I get an error:

> Unexpected Type Error (: $selReqs[i].val is not a function)

I have tried multiple variations of the below and cannot seem to get it to check if selected option has no value for each of the select fields. Any advice appreciated!

```js
var $selReqs = $('.allMinReqs');
var reqs = [];

for(var i=0; i < $selReqs.length; i++) {
 if(!$selReqs[i].val()) {
  reqs.push($selReqs[i]);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="minReqs">
    <div class="hide" id="singleMin_mcReq"><br> 
      <label for="singleMin">Minimum requirement for each skill: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
  <select class="allMinReqs" id="singleMin" onchange="showMcStart();">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="5">5.0</option>
    <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
    <option value="6">6.0</option>
    <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
    <option value="7">7.0</option>
    <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="hide" id="multiMin_mcReq"><br>
  <label for="curL">Listening requirement: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="allMinReqs" id="mcReq_L">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
  <label for="curR">Reading requirement: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="allMinReqs" id="mcReq_R">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry, I'll try to elaborate - depending on what user selects in previous radio selector, they would either see the first select field or the last two select fields shown in above HTML. I want to make sure that my array does not pick up the selected option(s) from the select field that was not made visible.

Comment: `$selReqs[i].val()` should rather be `$($selReqs[i]).val()`. Other than that, it's unclear whether you want to get the items without a value or whether you want to know whether all of the selects have no value. In either case, you could use `.filter` or `.every`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is because you're accessing a jQuery object by index. This returns the underlying DOM Element object which has no `val()` method.

To achieve your goal you could use `map()` to create an array of all the selected values. Then you can check the length of that array to determine if anything was selected, like this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var values = $('.allMinReqs').map((i, e) => e.value !== '' ? e.value : null).get();
  console.log(values);
  var somethingSelected = values.length != 0;
  console.log(somethingSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Check</button>
<div id="minReqs">
  <div class="hide" id="singleMin_mcReq"><br>
    <label for="singleMin">Minimum requirement for each skill: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="allMinReqs" id="singleMin">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="hide" id="multiMin_mcReq"><br>
    <label for="curL">Listening requirement: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="allMinReqs" id="mcReq_L">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
    <label for="curR">Reading requirement: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
    <select class="allMinReqs" id="mcReq_R">
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option value="4">4.0</option>
      <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
      <option value="5">5.0</option>
      <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
      <option value="6">6.0</option>
      <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
      <option value="7">7.0</option>
      <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      <option value="8">8.0</option>
      <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
      <option value="9">9.0</option>
      <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: That's very helpful thanks - not sure I understand quite what's going on in map part of function, but I'll do some digging! My question wasn't exactly clear - I'm trying to get an array that doesn't contain any of the 'Please Select' non-values..apologies for not articulating this properly in first place!

Comment: `I'm trying to get an array that doesn't contain any of the 'Please Select' non-values` That's what `values` contains. I've edited the question to log that to the console to make it clearer.